# Probability of the n-th dice matching in 2 groups of sorted random numbers

Tags: probability, random, dice

Say we have 2 groups of 6 6-sided dice. Each group of dice is rolled and then sorted so we have 2 groups of sorted numbers. What is the probability of each die in the group matching the corresponding die in the other group?

e.g.

Group 1 - [1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5]
Group 2 - [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6]

What is the probability that the n-th sorted die in group 1 matching the n-th sorted die in group 2?

BONUS 1: What is the general solution for groups of 'K' dice?

BONUS 2: What is the probability of the n-th sorted die in group 1 being within 'X' of the n-th sorted die in group 2.

Comment: We can only help you, if you show us what you have tried.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a good idea of where to start. Is it a part of the rules that you must show previous work to ask a question? If so I will try and work through my thought process and write it down.

Comment: Renchik: Yes, it is part of the rule. That you write down your thoughts is a good idea.